# Row Reference instead of Cell Reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I have a similar table in Sheet 2 which I would like to have cell references from this table in Sheet 1.

Instead of using individual cell reference, e.g. "=Sheet1!A2", can i reference to the whole row from A2:K2 instead of doing for every single cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short, No...**

If you want to replicate the data of each cell in Sheet1, your only option is to copy `=Sheet1!A2` across the entire range of cells you're interested in.

**However... the Camera Tool alternative *may* be suitable**

However if you just want to *see* the information from Sheet1 you could use the Camera tool.

To use the Camera tool, you need to customise your toolbars.

In Excel 2007, this looks something like this ([image from Chandoo](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/12/02/excel-camera-tool-help/)):

[image]

In Excel 2010 you can add it to your [Quick Access Toolbar](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/camera-tool-function-in-excel-2010/):

[image]

On Sheet1, select the range you want to appear on Sheet2, then click the Camera tool button. The cursor will change to a cross. Now go to Sheet2 and click in the top left corner of cell A1.

Position as you like, and remove the border (if you want) by right-clicking the image and selecting `Format Picture`.

**What makes the Camera Tool so Great?**

The wonderful thing about the camera image is that it's not static - if your data changes, the camera image will also change, automatically. It's a great tool!

**Brilliant for complex layouts**

For simple scenarios like this, it may be overkill but if you have several areas you want to display next to each other (especially with different column widths, row heights etc) the Camera tool really comes into its own.

Comment: Did try the camera function earlier, but due to the crop out image I decided against it. But anyway thanks for your kind advise.